# MSE needs the close reason "This question should be on SO"

Tags: feature-request, meta, close-reasons, off-topic

[Programming Puzzles & Code Golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com) has the following close reason for occasionally appearing general programming questions that should be asked on Stack Overflow:

> This site is for programming contests and challenges. **General programming questions** are off-topic here. You may be able to get help on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com).

Given the recent increase in confounded users who don't know the difference between SO and MSE, can MSE have a similar close reason?

> This site is for discussing the policies and issues of the Stack Exchange [network](https://stackexchange.com/sites) as a whole. **Programming questions are off-topic here.** You may be able to get help on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com).

Comment: Personally, I don't think there are so many that they require a special close reason beyond the existing "This question does not appear to be about the software that powers the Stack Exchange network, within the scope defined in the help center."

Comment: Custom close reasons should only be for *compelling* use cases that are not handled *at all well* by existing reasons. The general custom reason works fine here, and there's no additional guidance we can usefully give -- they're just completely derping their way on here and there's not much we can do about it at this point, seemingly, just close the questions quickly and quietly and let it go.

Answer (score 4):

Usually there are quite some programming questions asked on Meta Stack Exchange so I understand your request.

However, there are not much questions, maybe even not even a single question, that would be a fit for Stack Overflow and which would make migrating useful. Usually the questions are the worst of the worst quality, so it would be instantly closed and deleted on Stack Overflow.

The currently most used close reason therefore fits those questions:

> This question does not appear to be about the software that powers the Stack Exchange network, within the scope defined in the help center.